# React Jest issue when exporting server for integration testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, supertest

Quite simple situation, I am trying to import app.listen(port) for testing purposes. The tests will fail (fail reasons: app.address is not a function & server.close is not a function). Actually the server variable returns an empty object so the import is not done properly and that is the reason why the test cases are failing...

genres.test.js

```
const request = require("supertest");

let server;

describe("/api/genres", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    server = require("../../index");
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    server.close();
  });

  describe("GET /", () => {
    it("should return all genres", async () => {
      const res = await request(server).get("/api/genres");
      expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    });
  });
});
```

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

    module.exports = server;
```

Am I missing something about the import? 
Let me know if you need the more code lines/parts (note that the index.js I provided is not complete) or if you need the full error message.

I know this question has been already asked several times but in most cases, the solution is just to import app.listen instead of app, which I already did.
I also tried to use export default instead of module.exports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.

`index.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/api/genres', (req, res) => {
  console.log('api genres');
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

module.exports = server;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const request = require('supertest');

let server;

describe('/api/genres', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    server = require('./index');
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    server.close();
  });

  describe('GET /', () => {
    it('should return all genres', async () => {
      const res = await request(server).get('/api/genres');
      expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    });
  });
});
```

Test results:

```sh
 PASS   apollo-graphql-tutorial  src/stackoverflow/60321422/index.test.js
  /api/genres
    GET /
      ✓ should return all genres (289ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/60321422/index.js:11
    Listening on port 3000

  console.log src/stackoverflow/60321422/index.js:7
    api genres

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.693s, estimated 2s
```

Comment: I rewrote the APP from the beginning and it works now. No idea what the issue was. I should have done that before posting it, sorry for the noise.